# Kafka Log compaction issues

Tags: apache-kafka

After triggering a log compaction - Am running 0.9.0 and restarted with log.cleaner.enable = true, my Consumers are not working any more.

If I run `/kafka-consumer-groups.sh kafka-groups.sh --bootstrap-server 10.211.16.215 --group groupX --describe`

I get

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotCoordinatorForGroupException: This is not the correct coordinator for this group.
```

Any clues how to fix this. I could restart the brokers, But being a production system, I like to ensure it will solve or wont create further issues.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Hi ! did you solve this problem ? we've got the exact same problem right now ... but no solution yet .. tnx in advance :-)

Comment: Same isue here as well